# What is the difference between valueComponent and valueRenderer in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I dont understand the difference between `valueComponent` and `valueRenderer` from [`react-select` library](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

from the docs...

`valueComponent`: function which returns a custom way to render/manage the value selected

`valueRenderer`: function which returns a custom way to render the value selected function (option) {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [library `renderValue` source code](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/lib/Select.js#L936):

**`valueComponent`** gives you *full control* about how you want to render the value. Here you have access (through props) to children prop, events, flags and so on.

**`valueRenderer`** - gives you *partial control* about how you want to render the value. Here you have access only to the options properties, you passed to the `<Select />` component. So according to the below example, in `valueRenderer` you will have access only to `label`, `value` and `color`.

```
<Select options={[ { label: 'Example', value: 'test', color: '#E31864' } ]} />
```

---

In the official library docs you have a great examples, these illustrate the differences:

1. [`valueComponent` example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomComponents.js#L60)
2. [`valueRenderer` example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/649d1f4d978bc9d73956855a7ebd4c9669d11f4d/examples/src/components/CustomRender.js#L32)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jordan

Comment: For those of you using v1.x, the links are broken. Here are the examples: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.3.0/examples/src